# Performing I/O Port Access in PERL 5 Under FreeDOS

Tags: perl, dos

I've got a FreeDOS compatible copy of Perl 5 installed for use in an x86 platform. I've also added the **csdpmi7b** DPMI manager to the installation so that Perl will run correctly when accessing 386 type execution environment.

How does one program to access the I/O ports within a Perl script? If it requires the use of some library or support modules it would be very helpful if you could show me how to program that into a script that access I/O.

My interest to read/write I/O ports is to be able to create some hardware test programs.

Answer (score 0):

The device IO is essentially a file read and write. so 
you can use this:

```
use Fcntl;
sysopen(MODEM, "/dev/cua0", )_NONBLOCK|O_RDWR)
    or die "Can\'t open the modem: $!\n ";
```

the [Perl cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_15.htm) has a great example of this.

Comment: I'm not looking to do device I/O. I need to do port I/O. The I/O ports that I need to access are not supported by any device within the FreeDOS (or even MSDOS) environment.

Comment: [Sys::portIO](http://search.cpan.org/~andrewho/Sys-PortIO-0.1/PortIO.pm)  [Linux port howto](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming.html)

Comment: Are you sure? Linux != FreeDOS.